# Why did Phasma turn off the shield?

Tags: star-wars

[This girl](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phasma) seems to be pretty brave. Yet a bunch of resistance fighters can force her to turn off the shield, allowing the enemies to destroy the whole planet?

I mean any normal soldier would sacrifice his life for his country, rather than betraying thousands of comrades.

Comment: But she's not a normal soldier, is she? She's at the top. A leader, out to save her own skin, not a follower.